# 2 Model 2 foreach in 1 view. Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> I tried nested foreach few times. but i failed. How to foreach data choices. in duplicates foreach.

**Controller**

```
$choices = Choice::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->get();
$duplicates = Question::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")->groupBy('topic_id')->get(); 

return view('choices.index',compact('too','choices','duplicates'));
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
  <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;">@foreach ($choices as $choice) {{ $choice->question_number }} @endforeach</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

**I want result is like**

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
      <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">$choice->question_number }}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

> but it cant read that $choice

[image: Link Of picture]

Comment: Check what `$choices` actually contains by `dd($choices)` in controller

Comment: Please, explain what do you want and what is the problem you are facing. You cannot just throw a piece code and ask someone to fix. What this image shows? Your problem or your expected behaviour?

Comment: I want to foreach `$choice->question_number` by using `foreach($duplicates as $duplicate);`. thats why I'm using 2 foreachs @Ruman

Comment: So what is going wrong? What are you expecting and what are getting?

Comment: as you can see. it foreached all data in that i showed you in Screenshot. i want to foreach 1 by 1 with each `duplicates`

Comment: @RukaXing what is the relation between `duplicate` and `choice` ?

Comment: 2 different models. Choice, Question(duplicate)

Comment: yes, but is there any relation between choice and Question? I mean is there any question id in choice table ?

Comment: No sir. no. there is no relation between that 2 Models.

Comment: what output you want ? can you update that in Question ?

Comment: @rkj Please check . i updated my Question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173442/discussion-between-rkj-and-ruka-xing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From chat discussion, it seems `Question` model and `Choice` model has relation with `Topic` model

You need to define relationship like this

> Topic Model

```
public function choices(){ 
  return $this->hasMany('App\Choice'); 
}

public function questions(){ 
  return $this->hasMany('App\Question'); 
}
```

> Question Model

```
public function topic(){ 
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic'); 
}
```

> Choice Model

```
public function topic(){ 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic'); 
}
```

> Now Fetch data

```
$duplicates = Question::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")->with('topic', 'topic.choices')->groupBy('topic_id')->get();
```

> Template Render

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
      <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">
               @foreach ($duplicate->topic->choices as $choice)
                 {{ $choice->question_number }}
               @endforeach
         </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```